# is Dameon process is taking memory in RAM ,if number of Daemons process are there how INIT is parent of all daemon process

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system, signals

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
void my_isr(int n)
{
        printf("in isr pid=%d ppid=%d signal#=%d\n",getpid(),getppid(),n);
}
main()
{
        printf("hello  %d and bash id : %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
        signal(SIGHUP,my_isr);
        while(1);
}
achul@achul:~/chennai/linux/lan/sm_assignment$ ./a.out 
hello  4220 and bash id : 4150

achul@achul:~/chennai/linux/lan/sm_assignment$ ps -el | grep 4220
0 R  1000  4220     1 63  80   0 -   501 -      ?        00:01:22 a.out
```

here first i am sending SIGHUP to bash like " kill -1 4150 " so under that whatever process are there , all are receiving SIGHUP .. ok, now process 4220 doesnt have any PTS(control terminal ) . my doubt is if number of daemon process are there , its showing all having parent as INIT(1), so how INIT is managing and isnt wasting unnecessary memory in RAM ?

Comment: here process id 4220 is daemon process  if i am checking after duration of time its still showing                                                                               ps -el | grep 4220
0 R  1000  4220     1 63  80   0 -   501 -      ?        00:52:58 a.out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost unclear. But (roughly):

- when you kill the shell you are killing a session leader process, and that normally kills all its children. If this creates orphaned processes, they are adopted by init.
- one task of init is to `wait()` for the termination of its children (adopted or not), this to properly clean the process table avoiding zombies.
- when a process terminates all its address space is released (and every ressource is), so it does not use any memory anymore, except few bytes in the kernel process table (only if in zombie state).

Comment: when that memory occupied by daemon process is released .. on restart ?.. is there any way that user can check how much memory 1 orphan process is consuming ?

Comment: You must open a new question for each...new question. Anyway : use `ps`  or `top` to examine your processes and get their characteristics.